# Adding an alert that says "Not found!" if the input box on search bar is nothing

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am trying to add an alert that says "not found" when you search for nothing using a search bar that I have already programmed in JavaScript.
Something like this:

```
if (document.getElementById('query').value = *variable for nothing*) {
alert('Not found!')
}
```

This is example code. Can someone give me a line of code that would do this but is functional?

Comment: Nothing? You mean `=== null` or  `=== undefined` ? However `.value` will most certainly be `""` (empty string), not `null` or `undefined`

Comment: Another thing you can do, if it doesn't break the code is use `== undefined || == null || == 0 || == ""`

Comment: A single `=`, as you've used in the code in your question, is an _assignment_, not an _equality comparison_, so be aware of that potential mistake.  You likely want `===`

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the few cases where the solution is to write *no additional code at all*!

You can examine the *truthiness* of the `.value` of your element to see if it has a value in it.  That means you would check the condition:

```js
if(document.getElementById('query').value) {
```

If that's truthy, then it has a value.  If it's falsey then it does not have a value.

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (document.getElementById('query').value) {
    alert('It has a value');
  } else {
    alert('It does not have a value');
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="query" type="text" />
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

Comment: How would you use a ! operator? As in, if(document.getElementById)('query').value is not true)

Comment: Using `!` essentially inverts the condition.  Or you can think of it as having the effect of swapping which of the _if_ and _else_ blocks get executed for the same condition.  This is particularly useful if you have no _else_ functionality. First note that `if(c) { yes() } else { no() }`  and `if(!c) { no() } else { yes() }` are equivalent. Then, similarly why write `if(c) { /*nothing*/ } else { something() }` when you can write `if(!c) { something() }` and omit the _else_ block entirely.